# How to enforce Trunk-based branching strategy in Bitbucket?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, branching-strategy

As a code owner I'd like to enforce trunk-based branching strategy in my Bitbucket repository.

I tried using Branch Permissions, but once I set change prevention on all branches, I cannot exclude 'trunk' from it. I tried to set it in Workflow>Branches section, but seems there's no easy way to forbid pushing branches with names different than 'trunk' in this case.

How do I configure it?

Comment: TBD (https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/) is not about not creating branches differently than trunk... is about not them live too long (i.e: Using short-lived branches). So, I think checks should be focused more related to branch duration than branches names or existence.

Comment: Thanks for follow-up Gonzalo!

I'm more into allowing people to merge whatever branches they create to 'trunk' only thus enforcing only one branch ('trunk') exists in main repository for everybody to align